# Selecting multiple folders async in UWP with C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, uwp, picker

I'm writing an application where I need the user to select multiple folders that contain elements (pictures) I need to process. I can see in the UWP pickers PickMultipleFilesAsync and PickSingleFolderAsync, but there does not seem to be any PickMultipleFoldersAsync or anyting like this?

Any hints on how to do this and still complying to the UWP standard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no, technically there is not any **PickMultipleFoldersAsync** method, you can just pick 1 top folder and then query only the required files in it and all its subfolders as well with query : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-listing-files-and-folders

Moreover you can pick all items with :

```
IReadOnlyList<IStorageItemitemsList = await picturesFolder.GetItemsAsync();
```

This gets you all files and folders within the folder **picturesFolder** in this particular case.

> if you specifically want the **PickMultipleFoldersAsync** API in official SDK, you can vote it on [UserVoice](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/35464441-pickmultiplefoldersasync)

Comment: Thanks touseefbsb... Now what I need to do is to program one myself... Why on earth didn't Microsoft think of this? I'll certainly leave a comment on the UserVoice!

Comment: yes this is certainly something Microsoft shouldve included, please do post a request on uservoice and then share that uservoice here as well, I will include that in my answer so that anyone who visits this can also vote it.

Comment: and if my answer, answers your question please consider accepting it. Thanks

Comment: There it is! :) Please vote!

https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/35464441-pickmultiplefoldersasync